# How to add an icon inside a textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a search textfield in my toolbar. I want to add an image inside textfield (search icon at the left most) instead of some text.

Please provide some ideas to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you use font-awesome to load your icons. 
Once the Font Awesome library has been added, you should do something like this:

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mmp

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: 'Testing Panel',
    html : 'Contents of the Testing Panel',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    tools:[{
        xtype : 'textfield',
        fieldStyle : 'font-family: FontAwesome',
        emptyText: '\uF002 Find User'
    }]
});
```

Comment: I found something,this can be helpful in this context, refer this too. http://www.enovision.net/how-to-make-glyphs-work-ext-js/

Comment: Did the fiddle I provided answered you question? I read this tutorial you linked here but I don't think this would work for the input text placeholder like you asked here.

Comment: Yes, it answered my question. But I want search icon, unable to get the code for it.. :(

Comment: Replace the \uF007 with \uF002.. I have updated the code snippet

Comment: I did , but Iam getting this symbol ' fl ' .

Comment: Very nice and clean approach. Didn't know I could use it this way. I was thinking of a triggerfield, but this is much, much better.

Comment: Glad it helped, just as a note ExtJS 6 already comes with Font Awesome so there's no need to add the library anymore.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I needed the icon to always be present, so this is the solution I came up with ([Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2q9a)):

**JS**

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: 'Testing Panel',
    html: 'Contents of the Testing Panel',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    tools: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        cls: 'icon-textfield fa fa-search',
        emptyText: 'Find User'
    }]
});
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-textfield:before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 25%;
}

.icon-textfield .x-form-text {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```